# Is there a simple solution for importing different branches of software into a new git repository?

Tags: git, branch

A little background. We have a bunch of homebrew software in the lab where I work. Many of the projects stem from the same source, but has no version history. At some point several of them were forked for different experimental purposes. We are in the process of putting all that software into git repositories. Hopefully this will enable us to merge the different versions in the future.

I thus have to make a new git repository for say project1 versionA and call that master branch.

I then want project1 versionB to be a branch of the same git repository.

I haven't found neat solution for this though. My best idea so far was to do:

git init (in the project1 versionA) directory, then commit and push to remote repository.
then pull that in a new empty folder on the same computer where versionB is.
I then checkout a new branch called versionB and just copy over everything from that version on top of version A. I then commit -a and push.

That should give me two versions/branches in git. One called master (versionA) and one called versionB. The problem with this in addition to it not being a neat solution is that any files that are present in versionA, but not in versionB will now be present in both. This will definitely create confusion and since a lot of the software looks into certain folders and loads everything there this will be problems.

Another idea would be to purge the version A stuff from the version B branch before copying over, would this solve the problem?

This seems like a roundabout way of doing something that should be fairly simple (and often encountered)?

Comment: Do you want your branches to depend on one another? i.e. being merged or having a common ancestor? Are those branches initially unrelated?

Comment: They are related many years ago, but might now be different eg. some will have files the others don't have. The basic structure should be the same though.
The idea is to have them merged in the future, when someone has looked at the changed to each and considered whether they are relevant/pose problems for the other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you are doing this:

```
project1 repository
   versionA branch   A
   versionB branch    \--- B
```

Basically versionB is branching from versionA (master branch i guess), and you even left versionA's files in versionB branch because you just "copied it over". Commit A is your first commit.

Since you lost your project history and you don't have the code from were they forked, I'd recommend branching from an empty commit.

```
project1 repository
   master            M
   versionA branch   |---A
   versionB branch   \---B
```

Commit M would be your initial (empty) commit (maybe including only a `.gitignore` file or something), Commit A would've ONLY the files from VersionA, and Commit B would've ONLY the files from VersionB.

Answer (score 2):

> Another idea would be to purge the version A stuff from the version B
>   branch before copying over, would this solve the problem?

More or less.  After you have committed and pushed your master branch, create and `checkout versionB`.  Now `git rm .` (ie, empty the directory), copy in the versionB stuff, and commit + push that.  That *may* create a sort of messy commit record for the first versionB; OTOH it may not -- but that's just the difference between "modified fileA" and "deleted fileA, new file fileA" (I have done this before, but I can't remember the outcome in that regard).

Actually: might be better if you instead overwrite then just `git rm` the files you don't need, instead of removing them all first (unless that is too tedious).

Answer (score 2):

They are both 'project1' with different versions and you expect significant overlap between the two versions.  I'd do this (which is slightly non-standard).  Assume you have two directories, one called verAsrc and another verBsrc.

```
$ cd verAsrc
$ git init
$ git branch versionA master
$ git branch versionB master
$ git checkout versionA
$ git add
$ git commit -m 'Project 1 version A'

# now the non-standard part

$ cd verBsrc
$ ln -s verAsrc/.git .git
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/versionB      # change to versionB w/o touching working files
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m 'Project 1 version B'

# Now you are done with verBsrc

$ cd verAsrc
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/versionA
```

Now you have a git repository in verAsrc that has both version A and B on their own branches.  You can check either one out.  They are independent now; but, here is the key, you want to rebase versionB from versionA.

```
$ git checkout versionB
$ git rebase versionA
```

GIT will identify everything that is shared and produce just a single commit on versionA that takes you to versionB.  That single commit will have all the differences between A and B

```
$ git diff versionA..versionB
```

Should be good to go.  Merge what you want back to master.  Clone the repository in verAsrc.

Comment: I am unsure what the advantage of this more complicated solution is compared goldilocks or KurzedMetal? Is this to prepare for the merge immediately?

Comment: The other two approaches are changing the working directory (by copying or 'git rm' or whatever).  My approach says "we don't want to muck with the contents of versionA nor versionB; we just want to get them both into the repository unchanged"  Then, after it is safely in the repository you can use git commands to merge, rebase, diff, add, rm - whatever your next step is.  [Also, note - you do not need to do the 'git rebase versionA' that I described above; doing that depends on what you need after getting them both in the repository.]

Comment: @GoZoner; I tried your suggestion, but it fails when I do
git branch versionA master
>> fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.

So it seems that the major advantage of your solution goes away when I need to do an initial commit of master anyway?

Edit: Maybe I was too hasty. I guess I could do an empty commit first and then use the rest of your suggestion... I'll test this

Comment: Yes, my omission.  master doesn't exist until one commit.

Comment: I ended up not getting this to work. I think I am in over my head in refs and stuff. Using KurzedMetal's solution seems simpler and easier to understand. Thanks anyway.